# <tr>-margin mysteriously added when using <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Tags: html, html-table, row, margin, doctype

When I specify a doctype, my menu button table row suddenly gets a margin - 4 pixels above and 3 below.

Have a look:
http://twineboard.se/pete/index.php

I added doctype only to the first page. Navigate to other pages to see the table beautifully collapsed as should be.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you using a table for the menu and header? In this case as you're using images you can simply put them into a `DIV` and use CSS rules to position, it's what I do :-)

Comment: It's unrelated, but you should never use tables for layout like this.  It adds unnecessary code for you to maintain and makes your site almost unusable for disabled users relying on devices like screen readers, which will announce every table tag they encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, tables are an awful way to design a layout like that. Second of all, the `DOCTYPE` tells the browser how to render the HTML, it's very important for all pages. Thirdly if you want to fix that issue, try using a `CSS Reset` or setting global properties of `padding:0px; margin:0px;`

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using a doctype, then you are in 'quirks mode', and the box model for web pages is like it's 1995 all over again. The modern web requires a doctype and no pages should be created without one.

Comment: +1: all pages should have a valid doctype. If a bug appears when you add a doctype, then it is your page which needs fixing.

Comment: I agree, but this is more of a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Phil - the answer lies in the "comment". He wonders why things change with the doctype and therein lies his problem.

Comment: He's asking what the problem with the page is. Yes, this problem is crippled by not knowing what the `DOCTYPE` is, but placing one on all pages surely isn't the answer to his problem.

Comment: @Phil - Unless it is. The problem can't be fixed till he either sticks with no doctype, a bad idea, or uses a doctype while trying to fix any ongoing issue, if there is one. There's nothing further to discuss here.